# Iphone, user created labels?

Tags: iphone

Usually When i want a object to be accesed by many different event calls i just declare it in the h file.

However im making a app where i need to allow the user to create UILabels and drag and drop them where they want. So i have the code to make the labels and a alertview where they change the text.

```
-(IBAction)AddText{
UITextField *TextView;
TextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 40.0, 40, 40)];
[self.view addSubview:TextView];
```

Which works however i need the user to be able to create many textviews which each have a unique name and a way i can reference them later such as TextView.text, doing it this way always creates a object named TextView and i can only reference it from his event, otherwise its undeclared.

Im really stuck at how i would go about doing this if anyone could help it would be great!,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could think about adding the newly created label to a `NSMutableArray` or, better, to a `NSMutableDictionary`. This latter solution gives you the possibility of creating a dictionary in which each label can be referred to using a string key. If you put such a dictionary in your .h file you'll be fine, I think.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. Store the collection as an ivar, clean it up once you're done with it, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: This is a great soloution Thanks!, I was just wondering do i add the TextView object to the dictionary? or create some kind of refrencing system?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an NSMutableArray of NSDictionary items.  The dictionary items could have a reference to the label as well as things like name, and other relevant meta information.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the UITextViews to a collection of some sort, depending on how you want to retrieve them later.